# Select Query on Access Database in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, select

heres my code :

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    ltRooms.Text = CInt(Session("numOfRooms"))


    'Calculate total cost
    Dim intPrice As Integer
    Dim intTotal As Integer

    intPrice = AccessDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT [Price] FROM [Rooms] WHERE ([RoomType] = 'RoomType')"


    intTotal = intPrice * intRooms
    ltPrice.Text = intTotal.ToString

    End Sub
```

and my datasource

```
           <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
        DataFile="Hostel.accdb" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Bookings]"></asp:AccessDataSource>
```

I'm trying to store the value from the select query and then use it to work out the total price and then store it in a literal. So far I am only getting 0. No compile errors.

Does anyone one know why this isn't working?

Comment: What is the value of intPrice returned by the SelectCommand? If it is wrong then I would check the value of RoomType being passed to the query.

Comment: its 0, so its not even retrieving the value from the database.

Comment: RoomType is a string variable, Is that the correct way of passing a variable to a select statement ?

Comment: I think you need to format your SelectCommand to be something like this:
"SELECT [Price] FROM [Rooms] WHERE ([RoomType] = '" & RoomType & "')". If you put a breakpoint on your line starting "intTotal = " and run the app to that you should be able to see what the SQL query is.

Comment: cheers for the comment, Still getting 0. I put a breakpoint in as well, wouldnt give me the information I wanted though.

Comment: Okay, if RoomType is being passed correctly and you are satisfied that the correct information is coming back from the database query then another possibility is that intRooms is zero. Has intRooms been set correctly?

Comment: Yep I have verified intRooms. The correct information is definitely not coming back from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am consolidating the various comments into an answer for clarity and to stop the page complaining about extended discussion. This is all off the top of my head so there might be some errors in the code. It should be enough to pinpoint the problem though.

Firstly, now that I look at it again today, I think your code is just setting the [SelectCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectcommand%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property of the data source and not actually querying the database. I think you need to use the [DataSource.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.select%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method.

Your code might end up looking something like this:

```
AccessDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT [Price] FROM [Rooms] WHERE ([RoomType] = '" & RoomType & "')"

Dim intPrices As List(Of Integer) = AccessDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)

' Now do stuff with your price data.
```

If the above doesn't help then I would check the value of `intPrice` returned by the Select call. You should also check that RoomType is set correctly.

If the wrong data is coming back from the database then you should be able to fix your SQL query to retrieve the correct data. If you need further assistance with this then please post the SQL query and the table structure.

If the correct data is coming back then check where `intRooms` is defined. If it is zero then your total will be calculated as zero regardless of the value of `intPrice`.

Comment: You were right, I need the DataSource.Selected method as well. Thanks for all your help.